# Sails.js/waterline: Executing waterline queries in toJSON function of a model?

Tags: asynchronous, sails.js, waterline

I have the following model, let's say it describes a book:

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'String',
            required: true
        },
        type: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        book_id: {
            type: 'integer'
        }
    }
}
```

Here the 'type' attribute is the genre of the book, for example HorrorBook. I have a separate model for HorrorBooks, FantasyBooks and such, since the structure of the models differs from each other so much, they have fields the other doesn't have etc, which is why I can't just use a single generic Book-model. HorrorBook, FantasyBook etc each have their own 'id' fields, meaning there can be both a HorrorBook and a FantasyBook with the same id. When creating the book, I have a beforeCreate function that also creates an entry in HorrorBook or FantasyBook depending on the 'type' attribute of the book.

What I'm trying to do is that on queries on Book from the frontend, I'd like to include the relevant information of the book in an 'information' attribute, which is for example a HorrorBook entry.

```
toJSON: function() {
    var obj = this.toObject();
    switch (obj.type) {
        case 'HorrorBook':
            HorrorBook.find({id: obj.book_id})
                .exec(function(err, book_info) {
                    obj.book_info = book_info;
                    return obj;
                })
    }
}
```

However, this leads to the toJSON just returning null all the way. What I'm assuming is that the query being asynchronous makes it too slow or something, so it doesn't make it to the 'return' call at all. So what should I do about this? Is there a way to succeed in what I'm trying, or should I change my approach somehow?

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm assuming is that the query being asynchronous makes it too slow or something, so it doesn't make it to the 'return' call at all.

What's happening is that `toJSON()` is sync'ed and it's returning whatever comes out of `HorrorBook.find({id: obj.book_id}).exec()`, `undefined` sounds about right.

If you need to run something async your best bet is to create an async `toJSON()` [instance method](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models.md#instance-methods), for example (not tested):

```
toJSONAsync: function(callback) {
  var obj = this.toObject();
  switch (obj.type) {
    case 'HorrorBook':
        HorrorBook.find({id: obj.book_id})
            .exec(function(err, book_info) {
                obj.book_info = book_info;
                callback (obj);
            })
  }
}
```

And now you can get your result by doing:

```
book.toJSONAsync(function(json){
  console.log(json);
})
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding where and how I should use the second snippet. Can you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: Fissio, the second snippet is used where you are currently calling `.toJSON()` and getting `null`. `book` represents a record you've retrieved from your database using `.find()` for example.

Comment: Ah, I see - this unfortunately doesn't solve my problem then, since I'm making a request like `localhost:1337/Book?type=HorrorBook&id=1` from the frontend, and as such can't perform the query there. Sorry for being unclear about my situation before.

Comment: At the moment I feel like the best way to go about this would just be to create an own controller action for what I want to do, despite it causing some possible trouble in the frontend. Thanks for your answer anyway!